# Adapter Unable to fill data in dataset: Exception thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a drop down list on my web page, the selected item of which has to be passed to the Stored Procedure query in the database. However, I am getting a strange error here at `adp.Fill(ds)` in my bind method.

The exception always says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'to'.", where `to` is always the second word in the drop down option.
For eg: Items in dropdown- `9 to 5` (2nd word: to) , `age of empires` (2nd word: of)

Exceptions:
 
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'to'`
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'of'` etc.

Here's the method that I am using:

```
private void Bind(string ss)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Retrieve", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@s1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = ss;
    adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@s2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

StoredProcedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Retrieve_SegmentedQ]
(
    @s1 nvarchar(255),
    @s2 nvarchar(255)
)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

    SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (' + @s1 + ') AND UnsegmentedQuery=' + @s2

    exec sp_executesql @query
END
```

Any suggestions what's wrong here?

Comment: can you show your error screen shots

Comment: You can access the instance of your DataList in a static method? You should definitely make it non-static, this method and even more all of your controls. In ASP.NET every control is recycled at the end of the page-lifecycle and will be recreated for every new request. By making them static they will be shared by every request/user which is awfully bad. Btw, where are you opening/closing your Connection?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Sorry, that was a typo since I wrote it by hand, and didn't copy from IDE. Editted the method signature. About the connection opening and closing: SQLDataAdapter implicity does that. I have given the connection string as the parameter

Comment: @Cipher: Can you please edit the question so that the SProc name in ur Code and Proc itself looks same as quoted by Ankush Jain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update the procedure like below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Retrieve_SegmentedQ]
(
@s1 nvarchar(255),
@s2 nvarchar(255)
)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (''' + @s1 + ''') AND UnsegmentedQuery=''' + @s2  + ''''

exec sp_executesql @query

END
```

Comment: I don't get this. What's with the double inverted commas. They give me syntax error

Comment: It is not double  inverted comma. it is multiple single quotes. Since your parameters are strings, your final query in the @ query should have single quotes around the parameters. Ex: it should be like 
SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN ('FirstParam') AND UnsegmentedQuery='SecondParam'

Those are for that.

try Print @ query instead of sp_executesql and you can see what is inside @ query

Comment: @PraveenMenu: I got a part of your answer meant for the stored procedure. Further, does this mean the string parameter passed from C# should be of the this from: `'walk','from','here'` Comma-separated like this? Doing something like this: `'Param1','Param2','Param3'` gives me this error: `Procedure or function Retrieve has too many arguments specified.`

Comment: change the query like 
SET @ query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (' + @ s1 + ') AND UnsegmentedQuery=''' + @ s2  + ''''

(please remove the space after the @ symbol)

and the value of @ s1 should be passed from c# with single quotes and commas ex: 'cow','goat','dog'

Answer (score 2):

The bug is here:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (' + @s1 + ') AND UnsegmentedQuery=' + @s2
```

You have stored procedure but using it as query, so making something like sql injection. as result you will have following query:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (5 to 9) AND UnsegmentedQuery=age of empires
```

which is wrong.
make it in following way add single quotation marks to your params.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Details from tbData WHERE Name IN (''' + @s1 + ''') AND UnsegmentedQuery=''' + @s2 + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command text name should be same as your procedure name....and here they both are different